# 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, types

I am making an endpoint in Next.js. I want to enforce the JSON structure that is returned from the API endpoints, and it would be great if I can infer the return-type of an endpoint and use that in my React components.

I am getting an error and I cannot really pinpoint what the fix would be. This is a minimal reproduction of the code that gives a TypeError:

```
interface TestApiResponse<T> {
  number: number
  body: T
}

const testHandler = async <T>(): Promise<TestApiResponse<T>> => {
  return {
    number: 12,
    body: {
      slug: 'my-slug',
    },
  }
}

export default createEndpoint(handler)
```

`body` gives the error: `TS2322: Type '{ slug: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ slug: string; }'.`

Not relevent to the issue, but might be for your context. This is the createEndpoint function:

```
export function createEndpoint<T>(
  handler: (req: NextApiRequest) => Promise<TestApiResponse<T>>
) {
  return async function (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
      const response = await handler(req)
      res.status(response.status).json(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `testHandler` implementation isn't generic in `T` so the call signature shouldn't be generic. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvxkYN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That would work, but it would be great if the type could be inferred from the contents that are in that body, instead of having to write the definition first.

So in the example I would like to be able to do something like this:
`type TestApiBody = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof testHandler>>['body']`

Comment: Your `testHandler` is saying it can return a response for _any_ T. But it actually only returns one specific thing. I think you have your expectations about how generics work backwards.

Comment: @EmJee if you want to return a contant type and have type inference, couldn't you just remove the generic parameter (as per jcalz comment) and the specfied return type of the testHandler?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't currently support inference of generic type arguments in generic types like that; if you want such inference you need to use a generic function call.  You could write a generic identity helper function to give similar results, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W46bON). Does that fully address your question now?  I could write an answer if so, otherwise... what else am I missing?

Comment: "I want to enforce the JSON structure that is returned from the API endpoints" you can't naively do that at the type level. You basically have three options: tRPC, graphQL, and runtime validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant return type for your test handler, there's no need to make it generic - and there's also no need to specify the return type of the handler as it can be inferred.

Your `createEndpoint` function will still only be able to take handlers that return types that matches the TestApiResponse, and it will infer T here instead, so you will still end up with a correctly typed endpoint, if I understand your motives correctly :)

```
interface TestApiResponse<T> {
    number: number
    body: T
}

const testHandler = async () => {
    return {
        number: 12,
        body: {
            slug: 'my-slug',
        },
    }
}

createEndpoint(testHandler)
```

Comment: @jcalz and this time I tried it, sorry for my previous blunder :D